# how to get JSONP return format from this website

Tags: jsonp

On this websiet [Link 1](http://developer.hotwire.com/docs/Documentation_Page_2) we can find the info that they provide `JSONP` return format, but i cannot get it. 
I can only get XML return format.

I got XML format:
http://api.hotwire.com/v1/deal/hotel?apikey=xxx&limit=5&diversity=city

And how can i get `JSONP` return format?

Thanks,
Anna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They say adding a `format` parameter of `JSONP` should work, and it does.

http://api.hotwire.com/v1/deal/hotel?apikey=zs52rzyktcan2bjtkkq2c4ss&limit=5&diversity=city&format=JSONP

You're probably going to want to get a new API key now, by the way.